# Cannot read gmail from AWS with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, gmail, imap

I moved from Netfirms to AWS.  This code worked on Netfirms, but I get this error running on AWS:

Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [ALERT] - 
Can't connect to '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX': 1.

```
$connect_to = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$user = 'myaccount@gmail.com';
$password = 'mypassword';

$mbox = imap_open($connect_to, $user, $password) 
    or die("Can't connect to '$connect_to': " . print_r(imap_errors()));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to Gmail through IMAP with PHP - SSL context failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274911/connecting-to-gmail-through-imap-with-php-ssl-context-failed)

Comment: Thanks.  I had read that one.  I just says rebuilt php and openssl and the problem when away.  No real reason or solution to the issue.

Comment: @StevenV that question you linked is *completely* different...

Comment: Have you verified that port 993 is even available on that host?  That is, it's quite possible Amazon (or your image) has firewalled it.

Comment: I am actually getting to Google and they are replying in the error message.  Here's the message returned in full (I have logged in as they asked):  -Array ( [0] => Retrying PLAIN authentication after [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: http://support.google.com/mail/accou [1] => Retrying PLAIN authentication after [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: http://support.google.com/mail/accou [2] => Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: http://support.google.com/mail/accou ) Can't connect to '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX

Comment: Did you log in via your web browser as it says?  Google occasionally locks accounts and to unlock them you must log in via a web browser.  It is possible Google has identified AWS as a point of abuse.

Comment: @max thanks.  I did login and I cleared the messages, but still couldn't read them.  AWS support gave me the solution.  I clicked the link (https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) from my PC.  It replied that my account was unlocked.  Then when I tried the program again from AWS instance, it worked and now I can read gmail emails.

This had to be locked from the beginning, but I don't know how my other servers (Netfirms and my PC) were able to read, but not AWS.  One person guessed, because it was a new IP address that gmail blocked it right out of the gate.

Comment: @haymps, that worked for me too. You should add it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fixes it...

I clicked the link (accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) from my PC. It replied that my account was unlocked. Then when I tried the program again from AWS instance, it worked and now I can read gmail emails. This had to be locked from the beginning, but I don't know how my other servers (Netfirms and my PC) were able to read, but not AWS. One person guessed, because it was a new IP address that gmail blocked it right out of the gate.